# A nicely-spaced ASCII spiral

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Consider this spiral

```
###########
#
# #######
# #     #
# # ### #
# # # # #
# # # # #
# #   # #
# ##### #
#       #
#########
```

Starting in the centre:

- The first line (upwards) has 3 characters.
- The second line has the same number of characters (3)
- Next, we add two chars (5) for the next two sides.
- This pattern continues, two sides the same length then increase the length by 2.

I want to generate this spiral for N lines.

- Write in any language.
- The input/argument, etc. is the number of lines in your spiral.
- Each line starts with the ending character of the previous line in the direction 90 degrees clockwise of the previous line.
- I don't care how much whitespace is before or after each line, as long as the elements of the spiral line up.
- Output text to draw the spiral with any non-whitespace character you choose.
- Attempt to do this in the smallest number of bytes.

Test cases (using a hash as output):

N = 1

```
#
#
#
```

N = 2

```
###
#
#
```

N = 3

```
###
# #
# #
  #
  #
```

N = 10

```
###########
#
# #######
# #     #
# # ### #
# # # # #
# # # # #
# #   # #
# ##### #
#       #
#########
```

Comment: @Shaggy "Output text to draw the spiral with any non-whitespace character you choose." Yep, whatever you like.

Comment: [Related 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52494/print-an-ascii-spiral-in-olog-n-memory); [Related 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161011/asterisk-spiral).

Comment: The initial image has an `*` instead of `#`.  Expected?

Comment: @Wernisch It was intended to be a helpful starting point, but I suppose it's misleading. You can use any character you like.

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

#### Code:

Thanks to *Emigna* for saving two bytes!

```
LDÈ-Ì'#3Ý·Λ
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fx@Vwh@7hHnVl48NzD20/N/v/f0MDAA)

#### Explanation

The lengths of each individual edge on the spiral starts with length **3** and gradually increases every two steps by two:

$$
3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9,\dots
$$

For a spiral with \$n\$ edges, we just need to trim this list to size \$n\$. This is done with the following piece of code:

```
L                # Create a list from [1 .. input]
 DÈ              # Duplicate and check for each number if even
   -             # Subtract that from the first list
    Ì            # Add 2
```

This basically gives us the desired list of lengths.

```
     '#          # Push the '#' character
       0246S     # Push the array [0, 2, 4, 6]
            Λ    # Write to canvas
```

The canvas works as a function that pops three parameters (where the rightmost parameter is popped first): **<length(s)>**, **<char(s)>**, **<direction(s)>**. The directions parameter is in this case a list of numbers. The numbers that correspond to the directions are:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{r}
7 & 0 & 1 \\
6 & \circ & 2 \\
5 & 4 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$$

In this case, **[0, 2, 4, 6]** corresponds to the directions list `[↑, →, ↓, ←]`. The canvas iterates over each length retrieved from the list of lengths, uses the '#' character and cyclically iterates over the directions list.

Comment: `0246S` = `3Ý·`

Comment: @Emigna Ah I did not think of that, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>176</s> <s>170</s> <s>165</s> <s>161</s> 157 bytes

```python
g=lambda a,r:r and g(map(''.join,zip(*a))[::-1],r-1)or a
R=['#']
n=1
exec"R=g(['  '+l for l in g(R,n)][:-1]+[(n+2)*'#'],3*n);n+=1;"*input()
print'\n'.join(R)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU87T8MwEJ57v8IKg@3ERTjlmSpjWZEitpDBTdzUkF6sUyoofz7YlLKcP52/1/nTtB8xn9uxsyUlSTL35WAO284wo6ggZrBjvTgYLzi/fh8dqm/nRWqkrItiqRtFSy3HwIOqrPkVbwBLDfbLtklV9qLmjPFsYLtAGZjD4FUplE0dtVktMMtlGmVqlaJcY1bqdZI69MdJSPDkcOJveE4WlZxDQ3Ah4HPvBste6WgLWEx0CnPxy2YuoBjP4kmXbXhdsIbw01o/sc3L84ZopCjbkjUfAMA5h1jTxZpksLdCK61l4Pw7n8FOOPmHo2rWkMMKbuEO7uEBHuEJ9M38Aw)

Repeatedly: Uses `g` to rotate the `n`th iteration of the spiral into a 'canonical' position (similar to N=3 or N=7), adds a new segment by adding 2 spaces at the left of each existing row, then replacing the last row with all `'#'`s (resulting in a position comparable to N=4 or N=8), and finally using `g` again to rotate it back to the correct position. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki), <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)

```
↶ＦＮ«¶×#⁺³⊗÷ι²↷
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@Neil*.

[Try it online (verbose)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gsyy/xCc1rURD05rLLb9IwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1OzmktBIaAoM69EQykmTwmoBMYNycxNLdZQUlbScUxJ0TDWcckvTcpJTQFqL0lNTy1yySzLTEnVyNQx0gQCsDaQRUGZ6Rlgm2r//zc0@K9blgMA) or [Try it online (pure)](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9jaGFyY29hbP//4oa277ym77yuwqvCtsOXI@KBusKz4oqXw7fOucKy4oa3//8xMA).

**Explanation:**

Printing direction is to the right by default, and we want to start upwards, so we start by rotating 45 degrees counterclockwise:

```
PivotLeft();
↶
```

Then loop `i` in the range `[0, input)`:

```
For(InputNumber()){ ... }
ＦＮ« ...
```

Print a new-line to mimic the effect of moving back one position:

```
Print("\n");
¶
```

Print "#" `x` amount of times in the current direction:

```
Print(Times("#", ... ));
×# ...
```

Where `x` is: `3 + i // 2 * 2`:

```
Add(3,Doubled(IntegerDivide(i,2))
⁺³⊗÷ι²
```

And then rotate 45 degrees clockwise for the next iteration of the loop:

```
PivotRight();
↷
```

Comment: I assume there's no command in Charcoal for moving backwards?

Comment: @Emigna Not sure, but I couldn't find it either. Was indeed looking for one myself when I was writing this answer. There is a Move with a given direction, as well as a Jump with given coordinates, but not a MoveBack unfortunately.

Comment: `⊗÷ι²` is a byte shorter than `⁻ι﹪ι²`. Also, you can get the effect of moving back by printing a `\n` before the `#`s, which will allow you to remove the `»#` for an additional overall byte saving.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the `⊗÷ι²`, but what would the changes be for printing a `\n` before the `#`s? [The spiral is incorrect if I add the `Print("\n")`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gsyy/xCc1rURD05rLLb9IwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1OzmktBIaAoM69EQykmTwmoBMYNycxNLdZQUlbScUxJ0TDScckvTcpJTQFqL0lNTy1yySzLTEnVyNQx0gQCsDaQRUGZ6Rlgm2r//zc0@K9blgMA).

Comment: Because the arms now overlap you need to make them an extra `#` longer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>179</s> 178 bytes

thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for -1 byte.

```python
n=input()
S,H=' #'
m=[S*n]*(n%2-~n)
x=n/4*2
y=0--n/4*2
k=2
m[y]=S*x+H+S*n
M=[1,0,-1,0]*n
exec'exec k/2*2*"x+=M[~k];y+=M[k];m[y]=m[y][:x]+H+m[y][x+1:];";k+=1;'*n
print'\n'.join(m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxCoMwFEX3fIVYSjQx1YROhre7ODmmmYpQG3xKsZAs/noa7XLuefDuXcP2WlDFiDDh@t2KkgxVBzS7UDKDGRhaVuBViR1L4gHrO1MkQCPEXx0oMptgYWCedzz9kx6MrJpKJNh0jn580gOZqxVTLPccerM7q8MhKc/@AdN6m0ZO9Vy2VufacZCapp31M@FGH0hv72XCYi5jlM0P)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 179 bytes

In this approach formulas are used for `x` and `y` deltas instead of a lookup list.

```python
n=input()
S,H=' #'
m=[S*n]*(n%2-~n)
x=n/4*2
y=0--n/4*2
k=2
m[y]=S*x+H+S*n
exec'exec k/2*2*"x+=k%-2+k%4/3*2;y-=(k%2or k%4)-1;m[y]=m[y][:x]+H+m[y][x+1:];";k+=1;'*n
print'\n'.join(m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxCoMwFEX3fIVYJDFpqr46Gd7u7mgzFaE2@BSxEJf@ehrtcjhcLmfZt9dMEALhSMtnEznrri3y5MLZhH0nyUpBGegv5cwjFbUEtmOp9V8dApv63WInvWpV/LPBD09@IHEFSJCpV@gyDcpldXGXYHaNwmUwr0lccl2ZM3Cgb7yNlVO9qhprUuMUVobH7rKOtPEH8dt7HklMeQhV@QM)

Comment: `n+1+n%2` to `n%2-~n` for -1 byte. And I need to remember `0--n/4*2` being 1 shorter than `-(-n/4*2)`. Nice answer, +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 185 bytes

Sure this can be golfed more, maybe with currying, but here's my very humble attempt. Line breaks added for readability except penultimate character

```
r=(a,n=1)=>n?r(a.reduce((_,c)=>c).map((_,i)=>a.map(e=>e[i])).reverse(),n-1):a,
s=n=>n?r(s(n-1)).map((r,i)=>[...r,w,w].map(x=>i?x:'#')):[[w=' ']],
d=n=>r(s(n),1-i).map(r=>r.join``).join`
`
```

Usage: `d(10)` returns a string as per the N=10 challenge example.

Defines a function `r(a,n)` to rotate an array `a` by `n` turns; a function `s(n)` to generate a 2-dimensional array representing a spiral of size `n` by recursively rotating and adding spacing and lines (not rotated back to starting position); and a function `d(n)` to draw a spiral of size `n`, rotated consistently as per the challenge, and rendered as a returned string.

This was a really fun challenge :¬)

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <sup><s>20</s></sup> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｈ：２％！－├#×；↶ｎ｝╶├⟳
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JUY4JXVGRjFCJXVGRjVCJXVGRjFBJXVGRjEyJXVGRjA1JXVGRjAxJXVGRjBEJXUyNTFDJTIzJUQ3JXVGRjFCJXUyMUI2JXVGRjExJXVGRjExJXUyNTRCJXVGRjVEJXUyNTc2JXUyNTFDJXUyN0Yz,i=MTA_,v=8)

### Explanation

```
ø；｛：２％！－├#×；↶１１╋｝╶├⟳
ø                            push an empty art object
 ；                              swap with the input
   ｛                  ｝    for i in 1 to n:
   ｛：                ｝     duplicate i
   ｛ ２％              ｝    mod 2
   ｛    ！            ｝    negate
   ｛     －           ｝    subtract that from i
   ｛       ├          ｝    add 2
   ｛         #×       ｝    repeat '#' that many times
   ｛           ；     ｝    swap with previous iteration
   ｛             ↶    ｝   turn 90 degrees anticlockwise
   ｛              １１╋｝   overlap at (1,1)
                        ╶├⟳ rotate 90 degrees n+2 times
```